# Exoplayer(SimpleExoPlayer) 's addTextOutput is Deprecated?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm implementing about some Media Player, and this player have a many contents from many country, and almost stream has a text track about subtitle. I'm already check this point.

```kotlin
@Override
public void onCaption() {
    TrackGroupArray trackGroups = mPlayer.getCurrentTrackGroups();
    int groupIndex = -1;
    int textTrackIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
        TrackGroup group = trackGroups.get(i);
        if (group.length > 0 && mPlayer.getRendererType(i) == C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT) {
            groupIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
                Format format = group.getFormat(j);
                textTrackIndex = j;
                break;
            }

            if (textTrackIndex != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (groupIndex != -1 && textTrackIndex != -1) {
        TrackGroup group = trackGroups.get(groupIndex);
        Format format = group.getFormat(textTrackIndex);
        DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override = new DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
            groupIndex,
            C.INDEX_UNSET
        );

        mTrackSelector.setParameters(((DefaultTrackSelector) mTrackSelector).buildUponParameters()
            .setRendererDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, false)
            .setPreferredTextLanguage("ko")
            .setSelectionOverride(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, trackGroups, override)
            .build());
    }
}
```

At first, I used a `ExoPlayer` (not a `SimpleExoPlayer`), but `ExoPlayer` class does not have a method about adding text output in my project. So, now, I change my field about player to SimpleExoPlayer. But it still not work for me.

The version of my project's exoplayer library is 2.18.5. I think the method what I need (`addTextOutput`) was deprecated. If my opinion is correct, what can a use instead of `addTextOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `ExoPlayer.addTextOutuput()` was removed since [v2.16.0](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md#2160-2021-11-04). `onCues` can be overriden inside your `ExoPlayer.addListener()`:

```kotlin
player.addListener(object: Player.Listener {
    override fun onCues(cueGroup: CueGroup) {
        super.onCues(cueGroup)
    }
})
```